# button.Click event how to make it display decimal f

Tags: c#

**So I want button3 to calculate 'f' and display it in label21 but it doesnt 
    seem to work**

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button3.Click += new EventHandler(this.button3_Click);
        decimal b, f = 1;
        b = numericUpDown6.Value;
        while (f > 1)
        {
            f *= b--;

            label21.Text = f.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: What is the desired behavior and what are you getting?

Comment: i want it to calculate factorial and display it in the label, im getting nothing ,label still displays value its been set in the start of the project

Comment: And what does your code do wrong?

Comment: it does nothing thats the problem, maybe i`ve done something wrong

Comment: Are you getting the wrong value in your label?  Are you not getting any value in your label? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop is checking  (f > 1) & you initialise f=1, so it will never enter the while loop.

You need to be checking (b > 1).

Also there is no point assigning the label inside the for loop as GUI updates will only happen after the method exits,

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal b, f = 1;
    b = numericUpDown6.Value;
    while (b > 1)
    {
        f *= b--;
    }
    label21.Text = f.ToString();
}
```

Comment: it works ! Thanks, but now there is another problem, when I try to enter value greater than 2 it gives me this "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll"

Comment: I didn't notice that you were adding a new event handler every time you click on the button - this is not required. Remove that line.

Comment: You should mark the answer as correct as an aid to any body else with similar problem.

Comment: sure, I forgot :)